# Codeblocks on fedora 9 : Cannot build the C project

Tags: c, linux, codeblocks

I have a simple C console application named Test. But when I build, it says

```
  Test - Debug uses a invalid compiler 
    Nothing to do
```

What is the error?
The test.cbp(project file) contents are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_project_file>
    <FileVersion major="1" minor="6" />
    <Project>
        <Option title="test" />
        <Option pch_mode="2" />
        <Option compiler="gcc" />
        <Build>
            <Target title="Debug">
                <Option output="bin/Debug/test" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                <Option object_output="obj/Debug/" />
                <Option type="1" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Option projectCompilerOptionsRelation="0" />
                <Option projectLinkerOptionsRelation="0" />
                <Option projectIncludeDirsRelation="0" />
                <Option projectResourceIncludeDirsRelation="0" />
                <Option projectLibDirsRelation="0" />
                <Compiler>
                    <Add option="-g" />
                </Compiler>
            </Target>
        </Build>
        <Compiler>
            <Add option="-Wall" />
            <Add directory="/usr/bin" />
        </Compiler>
        <ResourceCompiler>
            <Add directory="/usr/bin" />
        </ResourceCompiler>
        <Linker>
            <Add directory="/usr/bin" />
        </Linker>
        <Unit filename="main.c">
            <Option compilerVar="CC" />
        </Unit>
        <Extensions>
            <envvars />
            <code_completion />
            <debugger />
            <lib_finder disable_auto="1" />
        </Extensions>
    </Project>
</CodeBlocks_project_file>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you install the ' gcc '?

Comment: That looks like the most possible cause.

Comment: No I have gcc installed. And its properly working. I also generally do by terminal. But I have a long code which is to be debugged. I dont want to go for netbeans, it takes too much memory.